# Telling python to ignore undefined data frames while iterating over a list of data frames?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this dataframe and iteration:

```
pdata= {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
pdata= pd.DataFrame(data=pdata)


for i in [pdata, vdata, odata]:
    i.index  = i.iloc[:, 0]
```

if any of pdata, vdata, or odata is not defined, Python throws the error:

```
NameError: name 'vdata' is not defined
```

Occasionally, I want to run the command while vdata and odata are not yet defined. What is the way to tell python to do the operation on the defined objects in the list and simply ignore the undefined ones?

Comment: Can you share your complete code so that I can reproduce it?

Answer (score 0):

Just skip over the errors with a `try-except` clause:

```
try:
    for i in [pdata, vdata, odata]:
        i.index  = pd.DatetimeIndex(i.date)
except:
    # You can do whatever you want here; pass does nothing
    pass
```

Comment: Copied and pasted your solutions; No, still gives the exact same error.

Comment: Ok that means the error is outside this part - try the edit above?

Comment: Generally bad practice to swallow base exceptions like this. Might be better to target NameError specifically.

Comment: @rvd I added a sample dataframe to the question. This would be my whole code. There is no other part. The code simply gets a list of data frames, and sets the first column of each as its index.

Answer (score 0):

```
pdata= {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
pdata= pd.DataFrame(data=pdata)

if pdata in locals():
    for i in [pdata]:
        i.index = i.iloc[:, 0]

if vdata in locals():    
    for i in [vdata]:
        i.index  = i.iloc[:, 0]

if odata in locals():
    for i in [odata]:
        i.index = i.iloca[:, 0]
```

I can't test this at the moment, but what if we check it in locals() in a if condition, would that satisfy? Try it out.

hard to reproduce since I don't have all the code.

Comment: I promise that is the whole code :) The code is simply there to turn the first column of a bunch of data frames into their indices. There is nothing more to that code.

Comment: Did you try my solution? From what I have been reading locals() keeps a dict of local variables so I was thinking it would be possible to check if said variable exists before trying to do something with it.

Comment: Yes, it says `TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

Comment: Building on your comment on the above answer, can we change that exception catch to catch only the name error, which is the type of error that happens in my case? I tried `except (NameError):` but did not work.